# When I generate .apk api calls return xhr.status = 0

Tags: android, api, cordova, xmlhttprequest

I have a really strange problem when I generate .apk file of my app.
When I do it and install my app onto an android device (nexus 4, 5, several htcs and others), all my api calls return xhr.status = 0 but If instead of doing that I use my devices as emulators and run the app from eclipse on them instead of install the app manually, everything works fine and all the api calls return  information.

So I don't have problem with my calls, and at first sight everything is ok, but during the compilation something has to happen that makes  this problem  happen and I don't know how to settle it.

any help please????

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check in your config.xml file whether you have  `<access origin="*"/>` in place.This is required to do cross domain api calls.

Answer (score 0):

We have realized that the problem happens while we signature the .apk, so something has to change in that process, with out signature the .apk works fine.

Any idea????

Answer (score 0):

we finally found the problem :

Phonegap/Cordova doesn't work with cross domain SSL request after exporting apk.

Any solution???